# Receiving this odd error with Vagrant, wondering if someone could lend a hand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant

I am trying to set up Vagrant. I am following the guide on the web site and currently have trouble with the Provisioning part of the guide (http://vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/provisioning.html) I have followed this thing to exactly as it is on the site but I am receiving this error, I am on Mac OSX if it's of any important

```
evan@superduper ~/vagrant_guide $ vagrant up
    There was a problem with the configuration of Vagrant. The error message(s)
    are printed below:

    chef:
     * Run list must not be empty.
```

Here is my code for the Vagrant file as well if this also helps:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
    config.vm.box = "lucid32"

    # Enable the chef solo provisioner
    config.vm.provisioner = :chef_solo

    # Grab the cookbooks from the Vagrant files
    config.chef.recipe_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/getting_started/cookbooks.tar.gz"
end
```

Does anyone what this is from and how I can fix it?

Thanks

J

Answer (score 6):

You need to add this line to your `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.chef.add_recipe("vagrant_main")
```

Comment: thanks!  this did the trick for me, don't know why it's not mentioned in the vagrant docs if it's required.

Answer (score 1):

In vagrant 0.6.0 and above you must add at least one recipe in your Vagrantfile, because the default recipe list is empty. Old Vagfiles have to be updated, to work with 0.6.0+

[Here is the change](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/commit/8f5dacef26a350966ea6b92bbd15e09e95537dc8).

I recommend you to read the [changelog](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) before updating vagrant. The project is beta, so the API is changing rapidly.

The author [promises](http://vagrantup.com/docs/backwards-compatibility.html) that the API will be stable at version 1.0 :-)